# matlab regexp exclude specific set of file extensions

Tags: regex, matlab

I want to exclude a set of file extensions and otherwise list folder contents.

```
%get filenames in current directory
p = dir(pwd);
p = {p.name};
p = p(1:min(end,20))'
%construct regular expression
%exclude = {'ini','m'}; %just for your convenience
reg = '\.(^ini|m)$'; 

%actually print file names/paths of files without a certain extension
regexpi(p,reg,'match','once')
```

This, however, does not work. How can I get the files that exclude these file extensions (last X amount of characters in path)? I tried `[^abc]` but this excludes individual characters, which I don't want. Please use regexp or regexprep in your answer

Comment: It should be `reg = '^(?!.*\.(ini|m)$)';`

Comment: keep in mind, the answer is not matlab specific (but PHP), and there may be more specific solutions. That said, yours worked perfectly =)

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> ```
> reg = '\.(^ini|m)$';
> ```

The `^` caret anchor comes after a `.` dot,
so it will never match start-of-string.
Remove it FTW:

```
reg = '\.(ini|m)$';
```

Comment: this is correct but doesn't answer the question